# Azure DevOps Pipeline test showing partially succeeded

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I've recently added my tests to Azure DevOps pipeline but when i run the test in the release pipeline i get the following error and a yellow symbol to say partially succeeded. How do i fix this issue?

```
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.
2019-05-02T08:36:57.6622077Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2019-05-02T08:36:57.6713607Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5):

This could be since Continue on error under Control Option is selected.

[image]

From the docs:

> The ContinueOnError attribute of the Task element controls whether a build stops or continues when a task failure occurs. This attribute also controls whether errors are treated as errors or warnings when the build continues.

more about [Continue on error.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-ignore-errors-in-tasks?view=vs-2019)

**UPDATE with Picture :**

[image]

Comment: Where can i find this option?

Comment: i updated my answer with picture, hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem when one of `ChromeDriver` instances wasn't disposed. That caused the chromedriver.exe to keep running after passing all the tests which in turn didn't allow `vstest` to complete.

Make sure to dispose all WebDriver instances by calling `Quit` method or similar, depending on the driver type.

Comment: I found the same issue in combination with Puppeteer Sharp and forgotten disposed instances.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13033#issuecomment-858623456 also points to hanging processes. I dont get it, why hanging are Interpreted as a failing task.

Answer (score 0):

In the Advance tab, there "Fail on Standard error" would be Selected for any of the task. That should mostly make the ADO pipeline to fail partially.